# Поясните значение необязательных параметров HTTP запроса

Tags: html, http

Зашел на локальный сайт своего провайдера. Затем прописал в адресную строку следующее:

```
http://luga.lan/robots.txt
```

В ответ получил:

> User-agent: Yandex
> Disallow: /engine
> Host: luga.net.ua

Comment: Причем тут robots.txt к параметрам http запроса ?

Comment: Угу, robots.txt - это для поисковых машин, http-запрос тут ни к чему!

Comment: Что такое необязательные параметры? То, что идёт в запросе `GET` после знака `?`, а в запросе `POST` в теле запроса? Или Вы имеете в виду поля заголовков запроса/ответа?
Если последнее, то они описаны в стандарте протокола rfc2616 (устаревший документ rfc2608). Перевод на русский rfc2068 легко найти в интернете

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос как-то странно переименовали.
Это файл robots.txt, лежащий в корне сайта, в нём содержится информация о том, что можно индексировать, а что нельзя + отдельные правила.

В данном случае:

- Указание для робота Яндекса
- Запрещать индексацию документов (страниц, файлов), лежащих в папке /engine *и во всех папках, лежащих внутри неё. (* тут она означает любую последовательность символов, она подставляется автоматически)
- На страницах с поиском отобразить сайт как luga.net.ua

[Помощью по robots.txt на Яндекс.Вебмастере](http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/?id=996567)